# Echoing to the same line in a Makefile

Tags: git, build, numbers, makefile, echo

I am trying to create a version.c file for GIT using git describe in Windows XP. For this I am calling git describe in my makefile as follows:

```
@echo #include "version.h" > $(path)/version.c  
@echo const char * build_ver = ^" >> $(path)/version.c
git describe >> $(path)/version.c
```

My problem is that I haven't been able to use echo to print to the same line so I can get something like:
const char * build_ver = "v1.1-4-g00a6d8f"

I have seen some other ways to get the version number from git, but using awk or perl is not really an option since I can't assume they will be installed on a particular system.

I've tried assigning it to a variable but it complains about createProcess.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

See [man 1 echo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo): you're probably looking for the `-n` switch.

If your echo doesn't support that, try [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf).

EDIT: since neither seem to be available to you, try echoing everything on the same line; something like:

```
echo 'const char *build_ver = "' `git describe` '";'
```

EDIT 2: sample makefile that works on Linux / GNU make:

$ cat foo.make

```
build:
        @echo 'const char *build_ver = "'`git describe`'";'
```

$ make -f foo.make
const char *build_ver = "2008.07.01-102166-1620-g89db338";

Comment: -n apparently is not supported because it prints it outright. printf is also not there saying: 'printf' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that only causes the words git describe to be printed on the line, no the result of the command.

Comment: Works for me. You're probably forgetting the back ticks around the git command.

Comment: Vanza: could you post your command? I've checked and I'm using the back ticks. Calling : echo 'const char *build_ver = "' `git describe` '";'  

Results in:
'const char *build_ver = "' `git describe` '";'

I'm using mysysgit on Windows XP

Comment: Vanza: Unfortunately no combination of escape characters actually makes git describe execute. Possibly it's because I'm using Windows. It always gets literally printed. Do you know perhaps how I can use a variable to store the output? I can run git describe separately but doing var = git describe doesn't work (has an createProcess issue). Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: It's going to depend on the version of make you're using, I guess. In GNU make you could do `MYVAR = $(shell git describe)`, but I'm not familiar with non-GNU versions so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of some code that I use that similarly creates a c file for you with build time and git version. This also includes the trick to get the "git describe" output into a bat file variable.

```
:: vss1_version.bat
:: This batch file will create a version c file that 
:: will contain the build date and time along with
:: version information extracted from GIT. 
:: This file expects git to be installed and excessable 
:: from the path

if "%1" NEQ "" goto deploy
echo usage: vss1_version [filename] 
echo i.e. vss1_version .\deploy\vss1\VSS1_VERSION.c
exit /b 1

:deploy

set VSS1_VERSION_FILENAME=%1

:: Delete the current file. 
rm -f -v %VSS1_VERSION_FILENAME%

:: Get time and day nicely formatted
set current_time=%time%
set ver_hour=%current_time:~0,2%
if "%ver_hour:~0,1%" == " " set ver_hour=0%ver_hour:~1,1%
set ver_min=%current_time:~3,2%
if "%ver_min:~0,1%" == " " set ver_min=0%ver_min:~1,1%
set ver_secs=%current_time:~6,2%
if "%ver_secs:~0,1%" == " " set ver_secs=0%ver_secs:~1,1%
set current_date=%date%
set ver_year=%current_date:~-4%
set ver_month=%current_date:~4,2%
if "%ver_month:~0,1%" == " " set ver_month=0%ver_month:~1,1%
set ver_day=%current_date:~7,2%
if "%ver_day:~0,1%" == " " set ver_day=0%ver_day:~1,1%
set datetimef=%ver_year%/%ver_month%/%ver_day%-%ver_hour%:%ver_min%:%ver_secs%

:: Format the date in YYYY\MM\DD-HH:MM:SS.ss
echo const char * build_time = ^"%datetimef%^" ; >> %VSS1_VERSION_FILENAME%

:: Get the output from a program into a local variable fo reuse later
:: Get the "git describe" information into a local variable GITVERSION
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('git describe --dirt^=*') do SET GITVERSION=%%i 

:: Put the git version information into the file
echo const char * build_ver =  ^"%GITVERSION%^" ; >> %VSS1_VERSION_FILENAME%

echo Created %VSS1_VERSION_FILENAME%
echo %datetimef%
echo %GITVERSION%

set VSS1_VERSION_FILENAME= 
set GITVERSION=
set ver_hour=
set ver_min=
set ver_secs=
set ver_year=
set ver_month=
set ver_day=
set datetimef=
set current_time=
set current_date=

:: Make sure we exit cleanly to the calling batch script will continue
exit /b 1
```